# Order in which PHP lists files

Tags: file, directory, php, http

Basically I have a php script that lists all the files in a directory and creates links to them. However it seems to order the files in a very arbitrary fashion (not according alphabetically/by date/ by size etc...). What way does php order the files? Is there any way to change this?

```
 <?php
    $orig = "/var/www/phplist";
    if ($dir = opendir($orig)) {
        echo "from: $orig";
        echo "<br><br>";

        while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        $ok = "true";
        $filename = $file;
        if ($file == "."){
        $ok = "false";
        }
        else if ($file == ".."){
        $ok = "false";
        }
        if ($ok == "true"){
          echo "<a href= '/phplist/$file'>$filename</a>";
        echo "<br>";
        }
        }

        closedir($dir);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but you can loop through the handle (like you do now), but then add all filenames into an array and then `sort()` the array.

Comment: Unrelated: Use real boolean values instead of `"false"`. Even better, use `continue` instead of the whole `$ok=...` thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) for this function explains what you're looking for:

> Returns the name of the next entry in the directory. The entries are
>   returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.

And depending on the filesystem, the files might retain the order in which they were created (FAT); might be sorted alphabetically (NTFS); might be sorted according to their position in a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) (ext4); or various other ways.

If you need files in a specific order look at [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) which takes a parameter that specifies the sort order.